# Matplotlib Runtime Error: main thread not in main loop

Tags: python, django, multithreading, matplotlib

I am not trying to thread any processes, but keep running into this error all over my Django site. I have seen a few other people ask this question but they are all attempting to use multiple threads.

This is on Django 1.11, Python 3.6, Matplotlib 2.0.0. I also will note that this issue occurs on my mac, but not on my live Heroku server.

I am using Pyplot to create some visualizations of models instances the users make, and get this about half the time I try to run it:

Exception Type:     RuntimeError

Exception Value:    main thread is not in main loop

The last line of my code that runs is simply the plt.figure() call

Trace:

```
File "/Users/Mark/Desktop/Professional/FSC/water/WATER/hydrograph/views.py" in processData
  397.         hydroFigure = plt.figure()

File "/Users/Mark/Desktop/Professional/FSC/water/WATER/ENV/lib/python3.6/site-    packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py" in figure
  535.                                         **kwargs)

File "/Users/Mark/Desktop/Professional/FSC/water/WATER/ENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py" in new_figure_manager
  81.     return new_figure_manager_given_figure(num, figure)

File "/Users/Mark/Desktop/Professional/FSC/water/WATER/ENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py" in new_figure_manager_given_figure
  98.         icon_img = Tk.PhotoImage(file=icon_fname)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py" in __init__
  3539.         Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py" in __init__
  3495.         self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)

Exception Type: RuntimeError at /hydrograph/
Exception Value: main thread is not in main loop
```

Any ideas on what I can do?

Comment: what do yo want to do exactly ?

Comment: I'm building a graph to encode as a b64 string. It's getting passed to a web page.

Comment: I think `tkinter` is allocating some resources and it takes time for them to get freed. Try to increase your trial rate and if you get more than half failure that would be the case. 

The problem is although you are not using multiple threads the server creates new threads for each request to be handled. The solution then would be implementing a worker to respond as a service to your website; the worker should have only one thread.

Comment: If you are using AJAX to call the python code making plt, it is being done in a new thread.